# Youtube api uploading video to website channel

Tags: file-upload, upload, youtube, youtube-api

Im making a website with user-generated content (pictures/videos) and I want to host videos that users upload to youtube on my channel, is there any way I can do this via youtube api?
What are the best practices for such thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is not to allow uploads directly to your channel, but rather to upload them to an intermediary server where you have a tool that allows you to check the content for abuse before it programmatically uploads the video. This prevents abuse and keeps you using reasonable quota caps.

Another good idea is to allow users to upload to their own channels and, via your app, to use the [playlist API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems) to automatically add their videos to your playlist.